# How to make some simple GUI controls?

Tags: c++, user-interface

I need to make a DirectX or OpenGL app and i will need a custom GUI for that.
I think a button, a input text box, a list box (that will need a scroll bar as there will be more items that can fit on the screen) and a slider control will be enough.
I know about CeGUI framework but i just don't like it, way too many XML files for my taste.
My question is where should i start in learning how to do this custom GUI controls, are there any tutorial available or any material that could get me started? I haven't done a GUI contol myself before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of googling turns up the following:

- [libnui](http://www.libnui.net/)
- [Bram Stein's UI library](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/gui/)
- [GiGi](http://gigi.sourceforge.net/)

... and then some.

Comment: "Bram Stein's UI library" is no more. It is an ex-page. It is pushing up the Web daisies.